# What is the jQuery equivalent of "this" in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As per title, is $('#id') the same as this, for example within an each loop?

EDIT: Let's say I have the following code

```
$('#id').each(function() {  
    var id = $(this).attr('id');  
});
```

What jQuery equivalent to "this" could I use instead of "this"?

I hope this is clearer.

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain it better

Comment: May know what is your question ? Or show your code and explain it

Comment: I would argue that jQuery is not JavaScript, but it uses JavaScript. JavaScript is a language, jQuery is a library that is written in JavaScript. As for the original question, you need to be a bit clearer as to what you are asking, perhaps write a code sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code

```
var $element = $('#id').each(function() {
   // here this refers to the native JS element. The same object that you get when you call document.getElementById('id');
   var id = this.getAttribute('id'); // this.id will also work

   // $(this) refers to the jQuery collection object, which is same as $('#id').
   var id = $(this).attr('id');

   // A jQuery collection is also an array of native objects, so you can also access the element using array access
   var id = $(this)[0].getAttribute('id');

   // This may not make sense in the above example, but when you have the collection as a variable, this might be the best option
   var id = $element[0].id;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's `$(this)`:

```
$('.class').each(function(){
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/qrzpk5wv/

Comment: Is there any chance of not using "this"?

Comment: You could go with a standard loop and indexes. But why would you like to avoid `$(this)`?

Comment: I'm trying to understand what "this" is and what it's equivalent in jQuery is. NOt finding a solution to a specific problem

Comment: I see... In the example above, `$(this)` is `$('.class').eq(0)`, then `$('.class').eq(1)`, etc... The scope change is done by jQuery, I think you'd need to dig into their source code to discover more details.

Comment: @AdrienHingert What exactly are you trying to do? `this` **is** `this`; it doesn't become invalid just because you're using jQuery.

Comment: `console.log($(this), this);` put this in the each loop above and see it for yourself.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what alternative I have in jQuery if I do not want to use "this"

Answer (score 0):

In `.each()`, the call back function receives the current index and elements as arguments, so you can use the element argument instead of `this`:

```
$('#id').each(function(index, element) {
    var id = element.id;
    // or:
    var id = $(element).attr('id');
});
```

Comment: I answered before he added his example that clarified. I've rewritten my answer to reflect that.